# Share state between components in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a dashboard using React. There are few components: **App**, **Block** and other child components, let's call them **Content**.

**Block** is a simple bootstrap card with title, classes and some css.
In **App** I call **Block** and pass in the **Content** components.
But in some **Content** components there are functions, which can change **Block** component (e.g. add or remove classes).

Now I use states in **App** and **Content** components to change **Block**, but I don't think this is the right approach.

Adding `setState` in **Block** component is impossible, as I know, because there is no way to change props.

How can I change **Block** states from within **Content** components?

Example:

```
function App() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Block
    id="users-component"
    title="Users Table"
    classes=[]
    content={
     <MyTable class="users" />
    }
   />

   <Block
    id="status-component"
    title="Status Component"
    classes=[]
    content={
     <Status class="status" />
    }
   />

   <Block
    id="bdays-component"
    title="Bdays Component"
    classes=[]
    content={
     <Bdays class="bdays" />
    }
   />
  </div>
  
 )
}

function Block(props) {
 return (
  <div id={props.id} className={props.classes.join(" ")}>
   <h2>{props.title}</h2>
   {props.content}
  </div>
 )
}

function MyTable(props) {
 return (
  <table className={props.class}></table>
)
}

function Status(props) {
 const handleClick = (title) => {
  changeTitle(title)     // changes title in Block
 }
 return (
  <div className={props.class}>
   <button onClick={() => handleClick("newTitle")}>New Title</button>
  </div>
)
}

function Bdays(props) {
 const handleClick = (class) => {
  addNewClass(class)     // add new class to array "classes" in it's block
 }
 return (
  <div className={props.class}>
   <button onClick={() => handleClick("newClass")}>New Class</button>
  </div>
)
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by moving Content components into Block body and using React.cloneElement. Now, it's look like this:

```
function App() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Block
    id="users-component"
    title="Users Table"
   >
    <MyTable class="users" />
   </Block>

   <Block
    id="status-component"
    title="Status Component"
   >
    <Status class="status" />
   </Block>

   <Block
    id="bdays-component"
    title="Bdays Component"
   >
    <Bdays class="bdays" />
   </Block>
  </div>
  
 )
}

function Block(props) {
 [classes, addClasses] = useState([""])
 [title, renewTitle] = useState(props.title)
 return (
  <div id={props.id} className={classes.join(" ")}>
   <h2>{props.title}</h2>
   {React.cloneElement(children, {addClasses, renewTitle})}
  </div>
 )
}

function MyTable(props) {
 return (
  <table> </table>
)
}

function Status(props) {
 const handleClick = (title) => {
  props.renewTitle(title)     // changes title in Block
 }
 return (
  <div>
   <button onClick={() => handleClick("newTitle")}>New Title</button>
  </div>
)
}

function Bdays(props) {
 const handleClick = (class) => {
  props.addClasses([class])     // add new class to array "classes" in it's block
 }
 return (
  <div className={props.class}>
   <button onClick={() => handleClick("newClass")}>New Class</button>
  </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it that way, you won't be able to share state between those components, since they're siblings (although I might get corrected on that)

You could instead, make `myTable` to be a child of `Block`, and pass a useState function TO `myTable` as a prop, that way you can change the state of `Block` from `myTable`

This is a sample implementation

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Block
    id="users-component"
    content={
     <MyTable class="users" />
    }
    />
  );
}

function Block(props) {
  const [headerText, setHeaderText] = useState("Marco!")
  return (
  <div id={props.id}>
    <h1> {headerText} </h1>
    <MyTable changeHeaderText = {setHeaderText} />
  </div>
  )
 }
 
 function MyTable(props) {
  return (
   <table className={props.class}>
     <tbody> 
     <tr>
       <td> 
         I'm a table and I can change my parent's header text!
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <button
         onClick = {() => props.changeHeaderText("polo!")} >Click me!</button>
       </td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 )
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have few different child components like MyTable and use multiply copy of Block in App with them as props. So it's impossible to put all of them to function "Block". And I don't now how people use components as template to put into them another components. They create this in every child component?

Comment: Could you clarify further with examples on how you're planning on implementing what you're saying?

Comment: I updated an example and added comments. I want to use "changeTitle" and "addNewClass" in <Block/>, without states in <App/>

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing it without putting state in the main App component. Your best best is using Redux, or the useReducer hook to make a global state that can be communicated across all components

Comment: Thanks for answers. I think, I’ll change project structure to avoid that problem.